# Add manual dependency references to SSDT project? (aka, force deployment order of objects)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

### tl;dr

Is it possible to add a manual "depends on" reference to items in an SSDT project? Or, during the build or publish steps.

I would also like to mention that the issue that is causing this need is not currently fixable. So "fixing the code" is not currently an option.

---

### Longer version

I am working on an extremely large and complex database migration into SSDT projects. One of the issues I have run into and have yet to find a solution for is forcing deployment order of objects.

I have read many other StackOverflow questions, blog posts, reddit posts, etc. Unfortunately, nothing has led me to an answer.

Here is the problem...I have a view which touches 4 different tables. That view has 3 `INSTEAD OF` triggers on it to cover Insert, Update and Delete operations. The triggers split apart the DML operations into the correct tables and then perform the action.

This allows you to treat the view as an ordinary table without having to worry about this error: `View is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables`.

SSDT does not seem to realize that stored procedures who perform DUI operations on the view depend on the triggers. So when SSDT generates the deployment plan, it creates the view, then it creates the stored procedure, then it creates the triggers.

So because the triggers are created *after* the stored procedures...SQL Server throw error `Msg 4405, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_Foo, Line 68 View or function 'dbo.vw_Bar' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.`.

However, if the triggers are created first, then it's fine.

So I need a way to force deployment order. SSDT controls this using "References" in the `model.xml` file. I can manually modify this file to add the dependency references myself. So each stored procedure that performs a DUI operation against the view, I add a references to the triggers on the view. I then recompute the file hash, update it in `origin.xml`, zip the files back up into a `*.dacpac` file and it resolves the issue.

---

So the question is...how do I automate this? I *could* build a script that unzips the file, scans the XML for views that have `INSTEAD OF` triggers, then scan for all elements with references to the view, and add references to the triggers. And this *might* work...but it's very hacky.

I have looked into Build Contributors and Deploy Contributors, but I'm still trying to understand what they do, their use cases and their abilities.

Comment: Clarification - "it throws an error". What does? Deploying the project? Or applications that are calling the stored procedures while the database is mid-deployment?

Comment: @BenThul SQL Server is throwing error Msg 4405 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors) when publishing the DACPAC and it is trying to create the stored procedure. This is not specific to SSDT as this same exception is thrown if you were to try to perform these steps manually in SSMS.

Comment: It might be worth coming up with an minimum reproducible error that we can bash against. I just tried with a new project (creating Person, Employee tables, a vwEmployee view with insert trigger, and a proc that inserts into the view) and the dependency order looks right from the deployment output. More important than the output examination, everything deployed w/o error.

Comment: @BenThul I can try and put something together, but I don't know if it will even be possible. I have no way of knowing what nuances SSDT uses to determine deployment order, and I'm dealing with a database that has over 2 million dependency references in the model. I will work reproducing it, but I don't have high expectations.

Comment: Fair. I'd start with pulling the relevant objects (i.e. the tables, views, stored procs) that are directly involved in the problem and see if it repros there. At least then, you can redact out company IP and/or try to pare it down even further. Good luck!

Comment: I would also recommend to minimize this example and publish it, so the people can experiment. I can provide you theoretical workaround with 2 projects and you'll probably need to deploy database project 2 times

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Like I mentioned above...creating an MRE is easier said than done. I'm dealing with a database that has millions of references and hundreds of thousands of objects (including constraints). So it could take me weeks to come up with an MRE for this specific issue.